# Letting 2 users see the same row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to have 2 users see the same table entry in pdo. The way i did it seems to be giving me different data from both tables.

Group A: `Rentals` < This is the data i'm looking for only, has a rental_id
Group B: `rental_group` < has a rental_id and a user_id.

What i'm trying to accomplish here is matching the rental_id's for each user. so if theres multiple users under the same rental_id, so they can all see the same rentals row.

I've tried:

```
public function getSomething() {
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM rentals JOIN rental_group ON rentals.id = rental_group.rental_id WHERE rental_group.worker = ?");
        $id = $_SESSION['userid'];
        $stmt->execute([$id]);
        if($stmt->rowCount()) {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $returnResults[] = $row;
            }
            return $returnResults;
        }
    }
```

This seems to semi work i guess, but its giving me different data if i was to `echo $row['id']` the id isn't coming from the rentals table.

`rental_group.worker` is the user.

Comment: This is primarily a sql question as far as I can see. Please provide sample data and expected result, and consider if the php part is relevant. Schema info might also be useful. Hard to know what the code will do without knowing what data its working on. See also [ask] and how to create  a [mre] of the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to be more specific with your query and the rental_group id might be overriding the rentals id. Try something like this:

```
SELECT rentals.*, rental_group.rental_id, rental_group.worker
FROM rentals
JOIN rental_group ON rentals.id = rental_group.rental_id
WHERE rental_group.worker = ?
```